# webdav clients can't upload files bigger than a few kilobytes

Tags: webdav, davfs2

I am mounting a webdav share using davfs2. The same folder is mounted on two different  virtual machines running Debian stable using davfs2. All options are identical (use locks 0 is set on both). The first machine works smoothly. On the second machine I can view the share and I can also create and edit very small files. For example

```
$ touch test
$ echo '123' > test
```

will create the file. Anything bigger (larger than 14 kilobyte) fails to upload. Looking through the syslog I can see that davfs does a PUT request but then I get

```
Aborted request (-2): Could not read status line
Request ends, status 0 class 0xx, error line:#012Could not read status line: connection timed out
```

I do not have access to the webdav server but it  is an owncloud version 10.0.10 installation.

I get the same behavior when using rclone instead of davfs2, so the problem is not specific to davfs2

Comment: Definitely 14 kB, and not 1.4kB?

Comment: After repeated tests it's actually rather random - it sometimes uploads 13kb files and other times it fails even with 5kb - rclone keeps getting "connection reset by peer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search I discovered that the two machines that had a problem were in the same local network. It ended up being a router issue with hairpinning. I have no power over the actual router hardware to actually fix the problem. As a workaround, using a proxy server bypasses the problem. In example

> $ export https_proxy="http://WORKING_PROXY_SERVER"
> $ rclone -vv copy testfile webdav-server:

works for rclone. Using the configuration option

> proxy  foo.bar:8080

works for davfs2.